# adding duration to time point has no effect

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono, libc++

The problem I'm trying to solve is given a date by `day`, `month` and `year` and `days_to_add`, add `days_to_add` to the given date.

I was able to convert the date into `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, ...>`. Now I want to add given days to it:

```
template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
auto add_days(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timepoint,
                                                  int days_to_add)
{
    constexpr unsigned int seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24;
    //                                      mm   hh   dd

    return timepoint + Duration(seconds_in_day * days_to_add);
}
```

But the result is unchanged `timepoint`. Here is the full program to reproduce:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timep)
{
    auto converted_timep = Clock::to_time_t(timep);
    os << std::put_time(std::localtime(&converted_timep), "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S");
    return os;
}

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
auto add_days(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timepoint,
                                                  int days_to_add)
{
    constexpr unsigned int seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24;
    //                                      mm   hh   dd

    return timepoint + Duration(seconds_in_day * days_to_add);
}

int main()
{
    auto today = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto tomorrow = add_days(today, 1);
    std::cout << tomorrow;

    return 0;
}
```

Wandbox link for [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B946PP4EZBVRtBJX) and for [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GlIiifkUy5sV9zKt).

```
2017 Jun 17 16:23:18
2017 Jun 17 16:23:18
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix, renamed variables before posting and made a typo here, the wandbox code is correct.

Comment: I just reproduced the bug in VS2013 (until I made some changes to be able to compile it). I see, how the internal data of `time_point` is changing but `tomorrow` is still `today`. My first guess: `Duration` does not take the time in seconds. (Thus, `60 * 60 * 24` is not a day but much less duration.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `std::system_clock` doesn't store its time in seconds, nor in milliseconds. Did you think microseconds? Nope. It stores its time in nanoseconds (at least on gcc, which you also seem to be using)! Actually, the time is implementation defined, so it is better to use portable solutions like the last one here.

You only think that the time point is not changing, but actually, it is, but in the time scale way smaller than milliseconds.

If you calculate the nanoseconds in a day, you'll get the correct answer:

```
template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
auto add_days(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timepoint,
                                                  int days_to_add)
{
    constexpr auto nano_seconds_in_day = 1'000'000'000ul * 60 * 60 * 24;
    //                                     (ns in s)       mm   hh   dd

    return timepoint + Duration(nano_seconds_in_day * days_to_add);
}
```

But that would only work if you pass a time point from `std::system_clock`. Other clocks can have a different `duration` and thus a different value needs to be added. You should use this version instead (which is also clearer):

```
<typename Clock, typename Duration>
auto add_days(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timepoint,
                                                  int days_to_add)
{
    return timepoint + 24h * days_to_add;
}
```

Comment: yep, should've just written `std::chrono::seconds(seconds_in_day * days_to_add);`, my bad. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think `std::steady_clock` is required to have a period of a nanosecond

Comment: @PasserBy Jup, you're right. Mentioned this. Thanks :)

Comment: With LLVM's libc++, `system_clock` measures microseconds.  On VS it is 100-nanosecond intervals.  Only the gcc implementation of `system_clock` ticks in nanoseconds.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ah, so it is implementation defined? Good to know, thanks :)